# Why I can get access to variable from multiple Tasks in Actor?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, actor

Why do these two **Task** run in parallel inside Actor? Doesn't this create a data race after multiple **value** variable accesses? Why didn't the compiler forbid me?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().task {
                await Actor1().performAsyncTasks()
            }
        }
    }
}

class Actor1 {
    var value = 0 // Data race?
    
    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        Task {
            for i in 1...10_000 {
                print("In Task 1: \(i)")
                value += 1 // Data race?
            }
        }
        
        Task {
            for i in 1...10_000 {
                print("In Task 2: \(i)")
                value += 1 // Data race?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because they aren’t running concurrently there are 2 separate tasks with no connection to each other, floating tasks like that are not good practice. You can remove the async keyword because it isn’t doing anything

Comment: Okay but how it's not produce data race? They a separated but they running at the same time, and they printed mixed.

Comment: maybe because value is valueType and every Task get new copy of value variable?

Comment: You should not change the core of your questions, if any of the answers below answer your previous question you should mark it as such then ask another question

Comment: @loremipsum I just realized this, so I returned everything back as it was, I had to rewrite everything several times to the very first option, sorry again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a data race. You can see this if you turn on the Thread Sanitizer under the Scheme's Diagnostics menu. In my tests, I get:

```
Data race in (1) suspend resume partial function for closure #1 
@Sendable () async -> () in test.Actor1.performAsyncTasks() async -> () 
at 0x112226c00
```

The problem is that Actor1 is not an actor. It's a class. If you replace `class` with `actor`, then the problem will go away. This is the point of actors. The compiler allows you to access a class this way because there are no low-level data race protections on classes. That's why actors were added to the language.

Tasks inherit the current actor's context, so if Actor1 were an actor, both Tasks would cooperate within the actor's executor and be run sequentially. The executor can only switch tasks at an `await` keyword, and there aren't any in your tasks.

Comment: You exactly answered my question! Thanks! Sorry again for bad post editing. I returned everything as it was originally)

Comment: But strangely I don't get crash... I made 10 attempts

Comment: There's no promise you'll get a crash. Data races are undefined behavior. They can do anything.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob Napier pointed out (+1), it is not thread-safe because you are using a class (not actor isolated) and as [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md) says:

> `async` functions that are not actor-isolated should formally run on a generic executor associated with no actor.

But you can change your “Strict Concurrency Checking” to either “Targeted” or “Complete”:

[image]

And if you do that, the compiler will warn you that this is not thread-safe:

[image]

I note this because run-time [TSAN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/#Detect-data-races-among-your-apps-threads) will not always detect the potential race (e.g., only if the race actually happens to manifest itself, not on iOS device but rather only simulator, etc.), but this compiler setting will always check your code correctness (with that build setting) and check your code at compile-time rather than relying on some run-time check.

---

You said:

> But strangely I don't get crash... I made 10 attempts

You may need a lot more than 20k iterations to manifest the issue. E.g., here, I ran in 20m times and removed the `print` statements:

```swift
class ClassNotActor {
    var value = 0 // Data race? Yes.

    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        let task1 = Task {
            for _ in 1...10_000_000 {
                value += 1 // Data race? Yes.
            }
        }

        let task2 = Task {
            for _ in 1...10_000_000 {
                value += 1 // Data race? Yes.
            }
        }

        await task1.value
        await task2.value

        print(value)
    }
}
```

And that resulted in 19,560,763 (!).

But if I change that to an `actor`, I get the correct result.

Bottom line, races do not always manifest themselves as crashes. If you are using higher-level objects (like arrays or the like), you are more likely to see a crash, but even that is not always the case. As you can see, the undetected data race sometimes silently generates incorrect results. The “Strict Concurrency Checking” setting can help you identify these problems at compile-time.

---

Now, the above is designed to illustrate 20m synchronizations, which is horribly inefficient. Obviously, we would rather let the two tasks run in parallel (with detached tasks or a task group), and have them use local variables. Thus we add 20m values in two parallel tasks, but with only 2 synchronizations:

```swift
actor AnActor {
    var value = 0 // Data race? Nope.

    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        value = await withTaskGroup(of: Int.self) { group in
            group.addTask {
                var value1 = 0
                for _ in 1...10_000_000 {
                    value1 += 1 // Data race? Nope.
                }
                return value1
            }

            group.addTask {
                var value2 = 0
                for _ in 1...10_000_000 {
                    value2 += 1 // Data race? Nope.
                }
                return value2
            }

            return await group.reduce(0, +)
        }

        print(value)
    }
}
```

That is an example of what we would actually do in our real projects to reduce the number of synchronizations while enjoying parallelism. We do as much work as possible with local variables, and then combine the results when the two tasks are done. (I also use a task group to avoid unstructured concurrency.)

Comment: Hi Rob, good to see you, thanks for your answer. I was interested in your story about synchronizations with the actor, can you tell me more about synchronizations with the actor in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76520576/why-withtaskgroup-work-runs-in-parallel-inside-actor)