# Why withTaskGroup-work runs in parallel inside Actor?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I understand that all the parallel work inside the actor somehow changes to serial as a part of some synchronization process. We can see that the **async let**-work that should be done in parallel is done sequentially in the **Actor1**, most likely due to the internal synchronization of the actor. But, **withTaskGroup**-work runs in parallel despite **AnActor** internal synchronization, but WHY?)

Edit: At the same time, I want to say that I understand how synchronization works when called from outside the internals of an actor when using **await**, but I don’t understand how synchronization works inside an actor, to call asynchronous parallel tasks inside an actor.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().task {
                //await AnActor().performAsyncTasks() // uncomment this alternately and run
                //await Actor1().performAsyncTasks() // uncomment this alternately  and run
            }
        }
    }
}

actor Actor1 {
    
    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        async let _ = asyncTasks1() // this not running in parallel
        async let _ = asyncTasks2() // this not running in parallel
    }
    
    func asyncTasks1() async {
        for i in 1...10_000_0 {
            print("In Task 1: \(i)")
        }
    }
    
    func asyncTasks2() async {
        for i in 1...10_000_0 {
            print("In Task 2: \(i)")
        }
    }
}  // the printed text are in series with Task 1 and Task 2 in console

actor AnActor {
    var value = 0

    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        value = await withTaskGroup(of: Int.self) { group in
            group.addTask { // this running in parallel, why?!
                var value1 = 0
                for _ in 1...10_000 {
                    print("Task1")
                    value1 += 1
                }
                return value1
            }

            group.addTask { // this running in parallel, why?!
                var value2 = 0
                for _ in 1...10_000 {
                    value2 += 1
                    print("Task2")
                }
                return value2
            }

            return await group.reduce(0, +)
        }

        print(value)
    }
}  // the printed text are mixed with Task 1 and Task 2 in console
```

Comment: Why would you expect those tasks to complete sequentially. A task group waits for all of its tasks to be completed or cancelled. It doesn't say anything about them executing sequentially. The point of a task group is to be able to dispatch a number of tasks in parallel and then do something when they are all complete.

Comment: You ask: Why would you expect those tasks to complete sequentially? But why then the tasks launched through **async let** running sequentially? For example if we change **Actor1** to class, we will see that **async let** will running in parallel... that is why I think that all custom actor have some synchronization of executed tasks.

Comment: Should a **async let** and a **withTaskGroup** start both in parallel? Why only **withTaskGroup** start in parallel?

Comment: you're absolutely right, but that's not the reason why `async let` running now in sequential. You said: The `await` is what causes the sequential processing. But I not using `await` in my code so it's must run parallel, but that didn't. If you change `Actor1` to `class`, we will see that `async let` will running in parallel as must.

Comment: If an `async let` is a shorthand way of saying `let _ = await asyncTasks1()`, why then we can use again `await` to get a result of function?

Comment: You said: "An `async let` is a shorthand way of saying `let _ = await asyncTasks1()` - The `await` is what causes the sequential processing" Is it really true? Maybe this not work that you think. Maybe `async let` is a shorthand way of saying `Task { asyncTasks1() }` and then optionally we can use `await`?

Comment: You should watch “Meet async await” the floating Task is bad practice an actor compensates for that “mistake” because it controls when tasks get processed, task group runs simultaneously because that is the design. There isn’t anything more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your first example:

```swift
actor Actor1 {
    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        async let _ = asyncTasks1() // this not running in parallel
        async let _ = asyncTasks2() // this not running in parallel
    }
    
    func asyncTasks1() async {
        for i in 1...10_000_0 {
            print("In Task 1: \(i)")
        }
    }
    
    func asyncTasks2() async {
        for i in 1...10_000_0 {
            print("In Task 2: \(i)")
        }
    }
}
```

You said:

> We can see that the `async let`-work that should be done in parallel is done sequentially in the `Actor1`

Yes, generally `async let` can let routines run in concurrently. But that won't happen here only because these two functions are both isolated to the same actor, and there are no `await` suspension points.

---

Someone said:

> If an `async let` is a shorthand way of saying `let _ = await asyncTasks1()` …

It is not. See [SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md).

If you want to see parallel execution, you can use `async let`. You just need to use non-isolated functions:

```swift
actor Foo {
    func performAsyncTasks() async {
        async let value1 = asyncTasks1() // this IS running in parallel
        async let value2 = asyncTasks2() // this IS running in parallel
        let total = await value1 + value2
        print(total)
    }

    nonisolated func asyncTasks1() async -> Int {
        await poi.interval(name: #function) {
            var value = 0
            for _ in 1...1_000_000_000 {
                value += 1
            }
            return value
        }
    }

    nonisolated func asyncTasks2() async -> Int {
        await poi.interval(name: #function) {
            var value = 0
            for _ in 1...1_000_000_000 {
                value += 1
            }
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

If I profile that in Instruments, I can see they run in parallel:

[image]

By the way, the above uses the following POI utility function:

```swift
import os.log

let poi = OSLog(subsystem: "Test", category: .pointsOfInterest)

extension OSLog {
    func interval<T: Sendable>(name: StaticString, block: () async throws -> T) async rethrows -> T {
        let id = OSSignpostID(log: self)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: self, name: name, signpostID: id)
        defer { os_signpost(.end, log: self, name: name, signpostID: id) }
        return try await block()
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it might be the reason that `these two functions are both isolated to the same actor`, but not it's interested for me how this `actor isolation` works? p.s. you said that: "and there are no `await` suspension points." you mean for `async let` result or you mean about `await` inside `asyncTasks1` or `asyncTasks2` functions?

Comment: I meant inside `asyncTasks1` and `asyncTasks2`. If, for example, they each were `await`ing some network request, then the fact that they were on the same actor or not becomes less relevant. They will run concurrently (each suspending at its respective `let (data, _) = try await session.data(for: request)`).

Comment: 1. I don't say this: *If an async let is a shorthand way of saying let _ = await asyncTasks1()* It's was an attempt to say that it works differently. This is not my statement - This said: Paulw11.  And I sad that *an async let is a shorthand way of saying Task { asyncTasks1() }*

Comment: I didn't mean to impugn anyone in particular. I was just saying that that statement is inaccurate. Re, “an async let is a shorthand way of saying Task { asyncTasks1() }”, that is a tad imprecise, too, as `async let` is structured concurrency, but `Task {…}` is unstructured concurrency. But I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is due to the nature of the async task you are performing when that task is bound to an `Actor`.

The underlying thread execution model in iOS does not allow for pre-emption. That is, the CPU is never "taken away" from a task.  When a task relinquishes the CPU then there is an opportunity for some other task to begin executing.

This code:

```
for _ in 1...10_000 {
    print("Task1")
    value1 += 1
}
```

is *CPU bound* - There is no opportunity for any other task to run on the Actor until the `for` loop completes.

Async/Await is normally used where there is some asynchronous operation; A network operation, for example.

If we make a small change to your functions:

```
func asyncTasks1() async {
    for i in 1...10_000_0 {
        print("In Task 1: \(i)")
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100)
    }
}
    
func asyncTasks2() async {
    for i in 1...10_000_0 {
        print("In Task 2: \(i)")
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100)
    }
}
```

you will see the output of the two functions intermingled because each function is relinquishing the CPU after each `print`, allowing the actor to execute the other function until *it* relinquishes the CPU.

Now, as for why you see a different behaviour with `withTaskGroup` - This is because the task group is not bound to the `Actor`, even though you are creating it in a function that is bound to an `Actor`.  A task group can use multiple threads to perform tasks. That is its primary function to allow a series of independent operations to execute with a simple rendezvous when they are all completed (or cancelled).

If you remove the `await sleep` that was added and make a small change to your task group code:

```
func performAsyncTasks() async {
    let a1=Actor1()
    value = await withTaskGroup(of: Int.self) { group in
    group.addTask { // this running in parallel, why?!
        var value1 = 0
        await a1.asyncTasks1()
        return value1
    }

    group.addTask { // this running in parallel, why?!
        var value2 = 0
        await a1.asyncTasks2()
        return value2
    }
    return await group.reduce(0, +)
}
```

You will now see that the two loops complete sequentially because they are bound to the `Actor1` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your example with withTaskGroup very helped me to understand what is actor isolation!